# Loop through textboxes on access form and change the data

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, textbox, vba

I am trying to change data when an access form opens. At the minute data says True and I would like to change that to say Yes instead. I have given it a go but I am new to vba and don't really know what I am doing. I have given all the textboxes the same Tag of 'QtTxtBox' hoping this would help but it hasn't. Below is what I've got so far, can anyone help me?

```
      Dim ctlVar As Control
      For Each ctlVar In Me.Controls
        If ctlVar.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            If acTextBox.text = "True" Then
               acTextBox.text = "yes"
            End If
      End If
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in your textbox reference. acTextBox is not a textbox. It's just a value showing that a control type is a textbox.
So, when you say '**If ctlVar.ControlType = acTextBox Then**', that is correct.
But when you say '**If acTextBox.text = "True" Then**', that is incorrect. You're not referencing the control any longer. It should be '**If ctlVar.text = "True" Then**'. ctlVar is your reference to the control.

Also, you need to set the focus onto the textbox before changing the value. Here's what your code should look like:

```
For Each ctlVar In Me.Controls
  If ctlVar.ControlType = acTextBox Then
      If ctlVar.Value = "True" Then
         ctlVar.Value = "yes"
      End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however .text threw an error message so I used .Value instead and that seemed to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Using .value, instead of .text allowed you to skip the .setfocus method. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things packed into this little chunk of code -- perhaps even your issue -- after two days of figuring this stuff out...

```
Function disorder()
  For c = 0 To 9
    s = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls("" & "[" & c & "]" & "").Caption
    r = Int(9 * Rnd)
    Screen.ActiveForm.Controls("" & "[" & c & "]" & "").Caption = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls("" & "[" & r & "]" & "").Caption
    Screen.ActiveForm.Controls("" & "[" & r & "]" & "").Caption = s
  Next
End Function
```

To make sure focus is on the form I want I used SendKeys "{ENTER}" which is picked up by a default button on the form.  In this case I have several controls named [1] and [2] etc to make it easier to loop through them but they could be named anything.

to loop through all the controls on a form...

```
For Each c In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
  With c
    If Caption = "" Then Caption = "New"
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score -3):

So - when you constructed the form you set the textbox caption to say True - correct? Well if you want to change that when the form loads then do the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

      acTextBox.Caption = "Yes"

End Sub
```

Comment: The textbox doesn't have a Caption property. Labels use the Caption property. Plus you made the same reference to acTextBox, instead of ctlVar.

Comment: @TomCollins the label part does yes - but i wasn't sure which part the OP was talking about.